# Is there any event triggered when highlighting a row?

Tags: acumatica

I created a ListView to show the list of documents, then created a button "Button A" to do some actions, my requirement is I would like the button status may be changed with the selected document changes.

Fox example: there are three documents in the following graphic, I want the button is enabled when I click Order-00001 or Order-00002, and it is disabled for Order-00003 due to no money in it.

[image]

I appreciate if you could give me a hint if there is any event to be raised when I click a row. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce callback to the server there isn't a row selected event. Instead there is PXToolbarButton StateColumn property to control the button enabled state.

When you declare your button, you specify a Boolean DAC field that will enable/disable the button based on it's value. Note that the button needs the DependOnGrid property set to the ID of the grid to get the selected row:

```
<px:PXToolBarButton Text="Button A" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="IsButtonVisible">
```

IsButtonVisible is a custom unbound Boolean DAC field (you may choose any name you want except isSelected/Selected which is reserved for checkbox):

```
#region IsButtonVisible
public abstract class isButtonVisible : IBqlField
{
}

protected bool? _IsButtonVisible;
[PXBool]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Is Button Visible", Enabled = false, Visible = false)] 
public virtual bool? IsButtonVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _IsButtonVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsButtonVisible = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

You can set the value of IsButtonVisible in the RowSelected event based on your business logic:

```
protected virtual void DAC_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    DAC row = e.Row as DAC;

    if (row != null)
    {
        bool yourCondition = ???;
        row.IsButtonVisible = yourCondition;
    }
}
```

Source:
[Enable disable button of grid or PXToolBarButton, which depends from value of column in Acumatica](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/enable-disable-button-of-grid-or-pxtoolbarbutton-which-depends-from-value-of-column-in-acumatica)

Comment: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA, I tried your solution and it seems it does not work. The button keeps enabled whatever I set the statecolumn is true or false, any further suggestions?

Comment: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA, can you please confirm if it is right that assigning the value of IsButtonVisible in RowSelected? I assume the issue is at here.

Comment: Can you post your code or compare it with the source link at the bottom of my answer? When it's not perfectly setup it does silently fail and does nothing.

Comment: Yes assignation in RowSelected for the DAC grid should work. If you have doubts you could also test by returning false instead of _IsButtonVisible in the property getter. That should at least confirm whether or not the variable is affecting the button state.

Comment: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA,  I figured out the reason of  why it is not working:  I need to add the "IsButtonVisible" field into the grid columns: 
 <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IsButtonVisible" Width="60" />   then, the program can detect it in the RowSelected event. To invisible it, we need to set  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Is Button Visible", Enabled = false, Visible = false)] for the field in DAC. Now all good and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I think you can set it's visibility to visible which adds it to the list of available columns using PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisibility<DAC.Field>(cache, row, PXUIVisibility.Visible) and still have it not show up in the grid by default by also doing PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<DAC.Field>(cache, row, false). Just read your edit, you got it right with the PXUIField attribute, it's equivalent.