# Action upon selecting a line in a grid

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to enable or disable a button upon selecting a line in a grid, here's what I tried for now :

```
    public virtual void ARRegister_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ARRegister row = e.Row as ARRegister;
        if (row == null) return;
        UnProcessLettering.SetEnabled(row.GetExtension<ARRegisterLeExt>().LettrageCD != null);
    }
```

And I've set the syncposition as true in my grid. But nothing changes when I select a row in which LettrageCD is not null or is null.

Edit : it seems my question is a duplicate : [Is there any event triggered when highlighting a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877150/is-there-any-event-triggered-when-highlighting-a-row) (didnt find it during my first search :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling SetEnabled on the PXAction, use the StateColumn property on your button aspx declaration.

When you declare your button, you specify a Boolean DAC field that will enable/disable the button based on it's value. Note that the button needs the DependOnGrid property set to the ID of the grid to get the selected row:

```
<px:PXToolBarButton Text="Button A" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="IsButtonVisible">
```

IsButtonVisible is a custom unbound Boolean DAC field:

```
#region IsButtonVisible
public abstract class isButtonVisible : IBqlField
{
}

protected bool? _IsButtonVisible;
[PXBool]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Is Button Visible", Enabled = false, Visible = false)] 
public virtual bool? IsButtonVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _IsButtonVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsButtonVisible = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

You can set the value of IsButtonVisible in the RowSelected event based on your business logic:

```
protected virtual void DAC_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    DAC row = e.Row as DAC;

    if (row != null)
    {
        bool yourCondition = ???;
        row.IsButtonVisible = yourCondition;
    }
}
```

Source:
[Enable disable button of grid or PXToolBarButton, which depends from value of column in Acumatica](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/enable-disable-button-of-grid-or-pxtoolbarbutton-which-depends-from-value-of-column-in-acumatica)

Comment: it doesnt seem to work, it doesnt refresh the status of the button :
    <ActionBar >
    
      <CustomItems>
        <px:PXToolBarButton Text="unProcessLettering" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="IsUnletterButtonEnabled">
          <AutoCallBack Command="unProcessLettering" Target="ds" /></px:PXToolBarButton></CustomItems></ActionBar>

Also it just added my button to the grid toolbar, but I was happy with having this button at the top of my page. 

[Screen](https://i.imgur.com/b9dkw08.png)

Which dac should I use ? The dac of the lines or the dac of my page header (filter dac)

Comment: You should use the primary DAC to define your actions. The one in PXGraph<DAC> or PXGraphExtension<DAC>. Unfortunately without DependOnGrid I don't think this technique would work.

Comment: Isnt it because I didnt add the field isButtonVisible in my grid as mentionned in the comments here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877150/is-there-any-event-triggered-when-highlighting-a-row ?
I'm going to try.

Comment: Yes adding the field in the grid is necessary, you can set the field attributes property to Visible=false and Visibility=PXUIVisibility.Visible so it doesn't show in the grid but is available in the column selection dialog.