# how to disable add/edit/delete toolbar button in row selection in Acumatica PXGrid?

Tags: crud, toolbar, acumatica, acumatica-kb

how to `enabled/disabled` `add/edit/delete` `toolbar` button in row selection in  `Acumatica PXGrid`?

I saw below post but i don't want to use this because i am using `Acumatica` existing `Form` view, i don't want to affect their `form` if our custom funcationality not available. Is there a way to use `row selection` event to  `enable/disabled toolbar button` or any other way to disabled buttons?

[Action upon selecting a line in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369916/action-upon-selecting-a-line-in-a-grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to override the RowSelected event handler (as you asked) to modify access to AllowUpdate, AllowInsert, and AllowDelete on the cache associated to that grid.

If the cache is already being set and you want to disable it, you can simply set the related cache.Allow--- to false based on your condition.

```
if(myAddCondition == true) MyViewName.AllowInsert = false;
if(myUpdateCondition == true) MyViewName.AllowUpdate = false;
if(myDeleteCondition == true) MyViewName.AllowDelete = false;
```

Remember that this will not inherently enable it again for the next row, so if you don't have code that already sets enable/disable, you should use the syntax:

```
MyViewName.AllowInsert = (myAddCondition == true);
MyViewName.AllowUpdate = (myUpdateCondition == true);
MyViewName.AllowDelete = (myDeleteCondition == true);
```

Be mindful that the base graph that you are modifying may have disabled the action on the cache already, so you want to be careful that you are not enabling it again unless you truly intend to do so.

Under certain conditions, you may need to refer specifically to the Cache of the view...

```
MyViewName.Cache.Allow[Insert/Update/Delete]
```

Comment: Brian, Once i disabled the button then it is not enabling for next row. I did same as you suggested like MyViewName.AllowUpdate = (myUpdateCondition == true);. Actually in new row selection post-back is not firing, SyncPosition is already true. Any thing else i am missing?

Comment: Are you enabling/disabling on the RowSelected event of the GRID view's primary DAC?  If you are putting it in the RowSelected of the view used by header, then it will not fire as you change grid rows.

Comment: My Grid DAC is not primary DAC,  I am enable/disable button in child Grid RowSelected event. Some of my rows are enable/disabled. Any thing else i am missing?

Comment: I mean the primary DAC used in the grid’s view.  For instance, if you are using joins, use RowSelected of the first DAC in the select of that view.  No other ideas without seeing some code.  What screen and tab/grid?

Comment: I am using SalesOrder screen, and i am putting RowSelected event in SOLine event.

Comment: Sales order use the query like that   
public PXOrderedSelect<SOOrder, SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>, OrderBy<Asc<SOLine.orderType, Asc<SOLine.orderNbr, Asc<SOLine.sortOrder, Asc<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>> Transactions;  and Event is    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<SOLine> e) {}

Comment: SOOrderEntry has an SOLine_RowSelected event handler already, so be sure you are overriding that and also calling it either before or after your code.  SOOrder_RowSelected is setting AllowInsert, AllowUpdate, and AllowDelete on Transactions.Cache.  There is a minor difference between Transactions.AllowUpate and Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate which I'm still not completely clear on.  If you only tried Transactions.AllowUpdate, try Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate.  Also, make sure your condition is resulting in what you expect.  I've had more than once that bit me.

Comment: Also, I'm using sender.AllowUpdate on my override, and sender is the object for PXCache.  I believe that is the equivalent of Transactions.Cache.  (Of course, since these are graph extensions, Transactions is really Base.Transactions)

Comment: Yes, Transactions is in Base. Do we need to override the RowSelected event of SOLine, I don't think i need to override selected event of SOLine. when i select row then RowSelected event is not firing, any reason of issue?

Comment: SOLine is the main DAC of the Transactions view, so if you want the buttons to enable/disable as you change lines of the grid tied to that view, that's the place you would do it.  Not sure what you mean by "when I select row then RowSelectedEvent is not firing".  The base graph controls the buttons on the SOOrder_RowSelected event which fires when you change SOOrder records (header).  You need the event tied to the SOLine if it is the SOLine that needs the DAC to be enabled or disabled.  There is something in Automation Steps that can be an issue also, but I don't yet think that applies here.

Comment: Also, your Event sample is using a different signature than the base one.  In this case, you should override the old style event handler using *protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseEvent) { baseEvent(sender, e); }*

Comment: I have done same as you suggested, But still RowSelected event doesn't fire when i select new row. May you check SalesOrder form whether it is fire RowSelected event on selection SOLine item?

Comment: When you say selection of SOLine item do you mean selecting an item or selecting a new row?  The event does fire if coded correctly and changing rows.  If it does not fire for you, it may be time to open a support ticket where Acumatica can review your code.

Comment: In my Grid has multiple rows, and all are saved, when i selecting the row then event doesn't fire, any other help?

Comment: I'm out of ideas at this point.  I would have to have a snapshot and your code to debug.