# How do I start a button in the disabled state on a Smart Panel?

Tags: acumatica

I want to pop up a smart panel that forces input before the OK button can be pressed. I've tried setting the button itself to disabled, linking it to the BLC through a PXButton declaration and setting it to disabled there, and setting the PXUIField Enabled = false on the PXAction/PXButton declaration in the BLC, but none of it works. Every time the option popup opens, the OK button starts enabled. Here are my code segments:

ASPX:

```
<px:PXButton Enabled="False" AlignLeft="False" runat="server" ID="CstButton13" Text="OK" CommandSourceID="ds" CommandName="DialogOptionPopupOk" DialogResult="OK"></px:PXButton>
```

PXAction Declaration:

```
    public PXAction<PMProject> dialogOptionPopupOk;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "OK", Enabled = false)]
    [PXButton]
    public virtual void DialogOptionPopupOk()
    { //No logic needed, only here to handle enable/disable of option popup ok button
    }
```

Popup DAC Row Selected:

```
    protected void OptionPopup_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        dialogOptionPopupOk.SetEnabled(false);
    }
```

Popup when opened:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new unbound Field of type PXBool. (EX. :IsButtonVisible )

Then you could use the **Statecolumn** property  and the **DependOnGrid** property on the PXButton(ASPX):

.................

```
<px:PXPanel runat="server" SkinID="Buttons" ID="CstPanel11">

        <px:PXButton runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="AddRows" DialogResult="OK" CommandSourceID="ds" ID="CstButton12" DependOnGrid="CstPXGrid14" StateColumn="IsButtonVisible" ></px:PXButton>

        <px:PXButton runat="server" DialogResult="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ID="CstButton13" ></px:PXButton>

    </px:PXPanel>
```

...............

Then on your code you can modfiy this new unbound field value depending on your conditions and at the moment(event handler) you need to change.

Please find more information about these changes here on this stackoverflow article:

[Is there any event triggered when highlighting a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877150/is-there-any-event-triggered-when-highlighting-a-row)

Comment: Based on OP business rules there's no grid control in the Popup though. I'm still under the impression that enabling/disabling buttons in PXSmartPanel without JavaScript is a limitation in the framework, can somebody provide a definitive answer on that?

Comment: HB, would it be doable with JavaScript? I could probably write some if it is.